# Using cytoscape with Qt

Tags: qt, qml, cytoscape

I wonder if one can use cytoscape under Qt using qml. I tried to import [cytoscape.min.js](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/cytoscape@3.23.0/dist/cytoscape.min.js) to a helloworld qml file as below.

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import "Cytoscape.js" as Cytoscape

Rectangle {
    id: page
    width: 320; height: 480
    color: "lightgray"

    Text {
        id: helloText
        text: "Hello world!"
        y: 30
        anchors.horizontalCenter: page.horizontalCenter
        font.pointSize: 24; font.bold: true
    }
}
```

But I got a TypeError: Type error on line 29.

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 and Qt5.

Comment: what do you want to do with this library? I assume that this library is designed for browsers so on what canvas do you plan do render that?

Comment: It may be possible to use it inside a [`WebView`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtwebview-webview.html). QML itself supports js, but that doesn't mean it supports all the variables and DOM structure that is supported by web browers.

Comment: Yes. I am hoping QT's WebView support would allow me to use cytoscape. I currently render graphs using cytoscape under plotly-dash. I would much prefer using QT instead if possible.

Comment: The reason why it will not work in QML is because it makes references to `window`, `document`, `document.body`, `HTMLElement` and does things like `window.addEventListener`. This limits the usage in a HTML page so, it cannot work in QML. HOwever, I observe only a small fraction of the library is like this. With a degree of effort, you could clean out these references and have it load. Some degree of explorative troubleshooting / hacking is required to succeed.